# Flink EMR Installation

Tags: apache-flink, amazon-emr

I am new to flink and trying to deploy this on EMR cluster. I have used 3 node cluster (1 master and 2 slaves) with their default configuration. I have not done any configuration changes and sticking with default configuration.

I am curious to understand the following points:

1. How does master and slaves communicate with  each other as I have not mentioned any IP in conf/slaves in master node?
2. I can see a flink library in master node (Path: /usr/lib/flink) but cannot find flink library in slave nodes. How is my code getting executed on slave nodes?
3. I will change some config according to my requirements in conf/flink-config.yml, if required. Do I need to make any other change on master or slave node apart from this?

Answer (score 2):

See the [Running flink-crawler in EMR](https://github.com/ScaleUnlimited/flink-crawler/wiki/Running-flink-crawler-in-EMR) wiki page for details on how we run a Flink streaming job on top of EMR. Note that in this mode Flink is running via YARN, thus the Flink `conf/slaves` file isn't being used. You should also take a look at the [YARN Setup](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/ops/deployment/yarn_setup.html) documentation to better understand how Flink runs on top of YARN.